# Create a soft reference to current Excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel

This question is about trying to prevent breaking of functionality when the name of the Excel file is changed.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a table where I collect data regarding visits and unique visitors for specific websites per month. I then use this data to generate three different charts. In order to keep these charts dynamic (i.e. not having to generate a new chart every time I add data for a new month) I use defined names.

Which leads me to my problem: I'm referencing my names like this: `=filename.xlsx!defined_name`. So the filename is hardcoded. Is there a way to use a soft reference to the file I'm working in (like using `this` or `self` in OOP to reference the respective object) instead of using the exact filename in every reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the INDIRECT function to make these type of soft references.

EDIT - If your charts are in the same workbook as the named ranges, then you shouldn't need to include the filename in the references, and you won't need the INDIRECT functions

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll look into it as soon as I'll have time. 
I moved the charts to different workbooks on purpose to remove visual clustering in the excel file. Maybe this wasn't the best idea ever.

Comment: So I finally got around to testing it. Using the INDIRECT function didn't seem to work for me so I just chose to move the diagrams to the same workbook the data is in. Thanks for your help!